# Why Storage.getItemSync() doesn't console log the actual value?

Tags: node.js, node-persist

```
var storage = require('node-persist');
storage.initSync();

storage.setItemSync('accounts', [{
    bankname: 'Chase',
    balance: 0}, {
    bankname: 'Bofa',
    balance: 0}
    ]);

var accounts = storage.getItemSync('accounts');
console.log('accounts are ' + accounts);
```

*Output:*
**accounts are [object Object],[object Object]**

How do I get the actual stored value?

Using node@5.4.1, node-persist@0.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to console log the list or object properly you have to json stringify the object.

```
console.log('accounts are ' + JSON.stringify(accounts));
```

You can use this if you wanted to stringify each object separately.

```
accounts.forEach(function(acc){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(acc));
})
```